# Flash AS2.0 - Read <li> tags from XML

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2

I have an XML document, and contained within one of the nodes, I have `<li>` tags. I don't need `<ul></ul>` tags for Flash because it only accepts `<li>` tags anyway. For example, here's part of the XML doc:

```
<node>
 <li>item1</li>
 <li>item2</li>
</node>
```

I want to put all the data within the `<node>` tags, *with bullets*, into a TextArea component in Flash 8.
Note that my textArea is set to accept HTML, and that

```
textArea.text = "<li>This is bulleted text</li>";
```

works just fine. However, the `<li>` tags within the XML document are being interpreted as a completely different node, which I obviously do not want.

I tried using a CDATA tag within the XML, and it inputted everything between the `<node>` tags, *including* the `<li>` tags with all their brackets. It does that because `<li>`'s brackets are being interpreted with the equivalent "& lt;" and "& gt;" for the left/right brackets.

So now I'm stuck with an unordered list in my XML file that I can't read into Flash. Unless, of course, somebody here can help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out I was throwing in .firstChild onto the end of my XML navigation string, meaning it would ignore all the extra `<li>` tags. Simply remove .firstChild and it returns EVERYTHING between the nodes, meaning Flash can read the `<li>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting in the text into the htmlText-property?

```
// you posted:
textArea.text = "<li>This is bulleted text</li>";
// it should be:
textArea.htmlText = "<li>This is bulleted text</li>";
```

Also, try putting the tags in uppercase, as2 can be a bit finicky about that.

Comment: The weird thing is, the top line works just fine, and using the .htmlText makes nothing show up at all.